# how to hide create and edit button from reports in odo o 11?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

How to set HTML report type without Edit button?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give options in XML for that specific field for hiding create and edit button. Like the following:

```
<field name="field_name" options='{"no_create": 1, "no_create_edit": 1}'></field>
```

I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Comment: In reports how can i hide Edit button ?

Comment: Which are you talking about the report? Can you please elaborate?